# Websockets 403 forbidden error for FastAPI + Gunicorn server

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, websocket, fastapi, gunicorn

I am currently experiencing a frustrating error when trying to deploy my FastAPI + gunicorn application to my Amazon EC2 instance. To give some context, I am initially running the server on the EC2 instance, and then accessing the server through an application that I have running locally. The application itself has both REST and Websockets. The REST API works perfectly. However, when I get to the stage of the application where I need to start using websockets, I keep getting a 403 forbidden error.

The server itself is setup in a reverse proxy configuration using NGINX. I have opened up my CORS origin policy to allow for all origins (as far as I can tell). I have set my AWS network rules to allow for connections on port 80. However, I still get the error. I am including my gunicorn logs.

```
DEBUG:root:Files uploaded and dedupe training initialized. Session ID: aa879fa76c070da3293ac705bea28e5e
[2023-05-07 15:29:48 +0000] [732] [DEBUG] = connection is CONNECTING
[2023-05-07 15:29:48 +0000] [732] [DEBUG] < GET /ws?session_id=aa879fa76c070da3293ac705bea28e5e HTTP/1.1
[2023-05-07 15:29:48 +0000] [732] [DEBUG] < upgrade: websocket
[2023-05-07 15:29:48 +0000] [732] [DEBUG] < connection: upgrade
[2023-05-07 15:29:48 +0000] [732] [DEBUG] < host: 3.133.140.121
[2023-05-07 15:29:48 +0000] [732] [DEBUG] < x-real-ip: 76.103.228.103
[2023-05-07 15:29:48 +0000] [732] [DEBUG] < x-forwarded-for: 76.103.228.103
[2023-05-07 15:29:48 +0000] [732] [DEBUG] < x-forwarded-host: 3.133.140.121
[2023-05-07 15:29:48 +0000] [732] [DEBUG] < x-forwarded-proto: http
[2023-05-07 15:29:48 +0000] [732] [DEBUG] < sec-websocket-extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
[2023-05-07 15:29:48 +0000] [732] [DEBUG] < sec-websocket-key: 3jtQM1t1V7oqIzMpsTgjEw==
[2023-05-07 15:29:48 +0000] [732] [DEBUG] < sec-websocket-version: 13
[2023-05-07 15:29:48 +0000] [732] [DEBUG] < pragma: no-cache
[2023-05-07 15:29:48 +0000] [732] [DEBUG] < cache-control: no-cache
[2023-05-07 15:29:48 +0000] [732] [DEBUG] < user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
[2023-05-07 15:29:48 +0000] [732] [DEBUG] < origin: http://localhost:3001
[2023-05-07 15:29:48 +0000] [732] [DEBUG] < accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
[2023-05-07 15:29:48 +0000] [732] [DEBUG] < accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
[2023-05-07 15:29:48 +0000] [732] [INFO] None - "WebSocket /ws?session_id=aa879fa76c070da3293ac705bea28e5e" 403
[2023-05-07 15:29:48 +0000] [732] [DEBUG] > HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
[2023-05-07 15:29:48 +0000] [732] [DEBUG] > Date: Sun, 07 May 2023 15:29:48 GMT
[2023-05-07 15:29:48 +0000] [732] [DEBUG] > Content-Length: 0
[2023-05-07 15:29:48 +0000] [732] [DEBUG] > Content-Type: text/plain
[2023-05-07 15:29:48 +0000] [732] [DEBUG] > Connection: close
[2023-05-07 15:29:48 +0000] [732] [DEBUG] > [body] (0 bytes)
[2023-05-07 15:29:48 +0000] [732] [INFO] connection failed (403 Forbidden)
[2023-05-07 15:29:48 +0000] [732] [DEBUG] x closing TCP connection
[2023-05-07 15:29:48 +0000] [732] [DEBUG] = connection is CLOSED
[2023-05-07 15:29:48 +0000] [732] [INFO] connection closed
```

Additionally, here is my current NGINX configuration:

```
upstream app_server {
    server unix:/home/tallyadmin/deduplication/backend/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    ''      close;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    server_name 3.133.140.121;

    keepalive_timeout 5;
    client_max_body_size 4G;

    access_log /home/tallyadmin/deduplication/backend/logs/nginx-access.log;
    error_log /home/tallyadmin/deduplication/backend/logs/nginx-error.log debug;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://app_server;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /ws {
        proxy_pass http://app_server;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_redirect off;

        proxy_set_header Sec-WebSocket-Extensions $http_sec_websocket_extensions;
        proxy_set_header Sec-WebSocket-Key $http_sec_websocket_key;
        proxy_set_header Sec-WebSocket-Version $http_sec_websocket_version;
    }
}
```

If am not exactly sure what is going on. When I run the server locally, it works perfectly. I am not even sure what my next steps in debugging should be at this point. What could be causing this issue?

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this? I've just run into a similar issue